# Loading Progres bar and 7 flv videos

Tags: actionscript-3, video, flv

So i have one big promo page. Where I'm going to streem 7 diferent videos. And I need to load the whole content before that.I'm going to do it with to swf files. The first one is going to be only the loader and the second one is going to be the one with the videos ( main ) . HEre is my code so far.... I need to know am I loading the movies + ( main )  or just loading ( main ) without the movies. Thanks.

This is the loader:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader()


loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);


loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);


loader.load(new URLRequest("main.swf"));

function onProgress(event:ProgressEvent):void
{

    var percentageLoader:Number = Math.floor ( ( event.bytesLoaded*100) / event.bytesTotal);



    myLoadText.text = percentageLoader + "%";
    myLoadBar.width = percentageLoader * 4.5;



}

function onComplete(event:Event):void
{

    loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);

    addChild(loader.content);
}
```

And this is the second one ( main )

```
stop();
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
nc.connect(null);

var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);
loader.Video_1.attachNetStream(ns);


var listener:Object = new Object();
listener.onMetaData = function(evt:Object):void {};
ns.client = listener;

ns.play("video_1.flv");

loader.Video_1.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,completefunc);
function completefunc(e)
{
gotoAndPlay (1);

}

loader.button_01.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, play_video_01);

function play_video_01 (event:Event):void{
    ns.play("video_1.flv");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work, but a better way to do this, is to explicitly tell your 'main.swf' to load the videos. You should think of these as separate Classes instead of SWFs. You can write a loader class that handles all the loading processes and a Player class which handles all the playback. I would recommend looking into Greensock's LoaderMax library. It has incredible documentation and can greatly simplify loading video and playback. http://greensock.com